# Xpages search view with exact matches

Tags: xpages

I am searching on an Xpage and the first column have these 4 values:

NAP
NAP/IFI
NVO
NVO Domestic

You probably see the problem. If a user searches for "NAP" they get both "NAP" and "NAP/IFI" as the = operator is really a CONTAINS! I didn't know that. In most universes = means exact match, not contains, but it is what it is.

The question is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Does this help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20097791/how-to-do-exact-match-in-ft-search-in-xpages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the Property searchExactMatch to the ViewPanel for ftsearches. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for this. However, I have run into a problem. When I turn this on, the query blows up - I get an error that says the query is not understandable. I investigated and it seems that I need to turn on the option for EXACT case in the index. So I deleted the index, turned this on, compacted the db, and then tried again and got an error. If I turn searchExactMatch to false, the query works again, but I had the same problem as before, getting too many matches. Is there a different way I must format the query. Would it be better to use the keys field?

Comment: Oh yes, i can reproduce it here. maybe this the solution for your "query not understandable" problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903013/xpages-exact-search

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by you can reproduce. What can you reproduce, the query not understand problem? I looked very closely at the link, and if I understand correctly, what the post is suggesting is to have computed fields on the form with extra characters in them, so you are kind of artifically making them unique. Is this correct?

Comment: I got the search to work by following what W_K suggested - making a search computed field for each key that added % to the front and the back. So the search value for "car" would be "%car%". This way I get exact matches.

Comment: glad to hear that it worked. yes i could reproduce the "the query not understand problem"... changed a search in one of my xpage dev applications to exactmatch.